# Parse file into list

Tags: c#, php, arrays, list, parsing

I'm parsing an file ( php ) to an list in C#, so that I can do stuff with it. I've done it before in PHP, but there it works really slow, so I'm trying to make an C# winform application of it.

This is the code that I already have in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace g7_product_parser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void log(String msg)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(msg + "\r\n\r\n");
        }

        public string[] parseLine(String regel)
        {
            string[] parsed;
            parsed = new string[2];
            regel = regel.Replace("array(", "");
            regel = regel.Replace("),", "");
            regel = regel.Replace(")", "");
            string[] temp = regel.Split(',');
            foreach (string part in temp)
            {
                string[] part2 = Regex.Split(part, "=>");
                // log(String.Join(",", part2));
                if (part2[0].Replace("'", "").Trim() == "keyword_uid")
                {
                    parsed[1] = part2[1].Replace("'", "").Trim();
                }
                else if (part2[0].Replace("'", "").Trim() == "product_uid")
                {
                    parsed[0] = part2[1].Replace("'", "").Trim();
                }
            }
            return parsed;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String startTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            log("Begin!");
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("tx_ttproductsv2_keywords_in_products.php");
            List<string> entrys = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
               // parseLine(line);
                log(String.Join(",",parseLine(line)));

                Application.DoEvents();
            }



            String endTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            String totalTime = (DateTime.Parse(endTime) - DateTime.Parse(startTime)).ToString();
            log("Klaar!");
            log("Start Tijd: " + startTime + "\r\nEind Tijd: " + endTime + "\r\nTotale Tijd: " + totalTime);
        }


    }
}
```

The file to parse looks like this:

```
array('uid' => '1','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '1','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '15','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '2','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '2','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '12','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '3','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '3','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '12','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '4','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '4','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '9','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '5','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '5','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '18','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '6','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '6','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '7','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '7','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '8','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '8','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '9','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '9','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '79','in_title' => '1'),
array('uid' => '10','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '10','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '11','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '11','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '12','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '12','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '13','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '13','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '14','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '14','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '15','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '15','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '15','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '16','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '16','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '12','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '17','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '17','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '12','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '18','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '18','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '19','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '19','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '15','in_title' => '1'),
array('uid' => '20','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '20','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '6','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '21','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '21','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '15','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '22','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '22','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '21','in_title' => '0'),
array('uid' => '23','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '23','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '12','in_title' => '0'),
```

I had some PHP code like this:

```
require_once 'export/tx_ttproductsv2_keywords_in_products_part.php';
$sql = new Sql;
    $tagList = array();
    $counter = 0;
    $counter2 = 0;
    $counter3 = 0;

    foreach ($tx_ttproductsv2_keywords_in_products as $key => $value) {
        $keywordsList = $sql -> getKeyWords($value['keyword_uid']);
        foreach ($keywordsList as $key2 => $value2) {
            if(isset($tagList[$value['product_uid']])){
                $tagList[$value['product_uid']] .= ", " . $value2['keyword'];
            }else{
                $tagList[$value['product_uid']] = $value2['keyword'];
            }
        }
    }
```

In this way ( in PHP ), i check if an entry in the array already excist, and if that's true, append, or else make an new entry.

My question is: how can I do that in C#. I think that I have to use an list, but I really don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a quick and dirty Console program to convert that into an array. See if you can modify it to your purposes... if not, please explain in more detail what exactly you need it to do.

(Note: this was a quick rush job and is not the most efficient way of handling this.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace simplearraything
{
class myarrayitem
{
    public int uid;
    public int pid;
    public int keyword_uid;
    public int product_uid;
    public int amount;
    public int in_title;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //array('uid' => '23','pid' => '2','keyword_uid' => '23','product_uid' => '1','amount' => '12','in_title' => '0'),
        string Original = File.ReadAllText("array.txt").Replace("array('uid' => '", "").Replace(
            "','pid' => '", "/").Replace("','keyword_uid' => '", "/").Replace("','product_uid' => '", "/").Replace(
            "','amount' => '", "/").Replace("','in_title' => '", "/").Replace("'),", "").Replace("\r","");
        string[] lines = Original.Split('\n');
        List<myarrayitem> mystuff = new List<myarrayitem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] thisitem = lines[i].Split('/');
            myarrayitem item = new myarrayitem();
            item.uid = int.Parse(thisitem[0]);
            item.pid = int.Parse(thisitem[1]);
            item.keyword_uid = int.Parse(thisitem[2]);
            item.product_uid = int.Parse(thisitem[3]);
            item.amount = int.Parse(thisitem[4]);
            item.in_title = int.Parse(thisitem[5]);
            mystuff.Add(item);
        }


        // Now, output it to prove accuracy:
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UID:" + mystuff[i].uid.ToString() + "/PID:" + mystuff[i].pid.ToString() + "/KEYWORD_UID:" + mystuff[i].keyword_uid.ToString() +
                "/PRODUCT_UID:" + mystuff[i].product_uid.ToString() + "/amount:" + mystuff[i].amount.ToString() + "/in_title:" + mystuff[i].in_title.ToString());
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

In response to comment:

```
List<myarrayitem> items new List<myarrayitem>();
for (int i = 0;i < mystuff.Count;i++)
{
      if (mystuff[i].product_uid == PRODUCT_UID_HERE)
      {
            items.add(mystuff[i]);
            // Or, instead of this items List, you could just do whatever you wanted to do with the items right here.
      }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. Is it possible with this that i can get all items with the same product_uid at the same time?

Comment: @Mathlight Sure! I edited my answerpost with some sample code of one way you can do that. It's pretty simple...

Comment: But will this method not make a huge overhead? Because i've got thousands of products, and for each product i've got to scroll to the list???

Comment: It makes very very little overhead compared to the required overhead of just reading the data from that file instead of internal storage. Oh but you could also make lists for each product or something. That's just a one-time power waster then it would save power. (EG, create a list of lists of items. The index in the first list is the product_uid... and the sub-list at that index is all the products by that ID)

Comment: I think i will puzzle that last suggestion out. Thank you anywhay for the code's and the ideas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Get [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/)
2. Add the following classes to your code:

> ```
> public class DataArray {
>   public string uid { get; set; }
>   public string pid { get; set; }
>   public string keyword_uid { get; set; }
>   public string product_uid { get; set; }
>   public string amount { get; set; }
>   public string in_title { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class RootObject {
>   public DataArray DataArray { get; set; }
> }
> ```

1. Load the file into a String called toProcess, then run the following:

> // the next 4 lines convert that data into JSON format
>       toProcess = toProcess.Replace("array(", "{\"DataArray\":{");
>       toProcess = toProcess.Replace(")", "}}");
>       toProcess = toProcess.Replace("'", "\"");
>       toProcess = "[" + toProcess.Replace("=>", ":") + "]";
>
> ```
> List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(toProcess); 
>
> foreach ( RootObject d in data ) {    
>   // do something here like..
>   if (d.DataArray.uid == "1") {
>       //
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hy, thanks for your answer. Why do you have an downvote? Because it looks good to me?

Comment: @Mathlight: Who knows.  Some downvotes are simply from other people that answer in hopes of keeping their answer on top.  No idea if that's the case here but whatever.